# how many classifiers needed in a content based Recommender system using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, recommendation-engine

I want to develop a content based recommender system using Machine learning approaches.
I am planning to use SVM/Neural Network/KNN classifier for this. I have collected data from 300 users. This can also be seen as a user interest modeling problem.

I have following doubts.

1. Do we need to train classifiers for each user separately ?? This does not seem to be scalable.
2. If yes how do we show final evaluation result ?? precision/recall for each user separately ??

Thanks,
Atish

Answer (score 0):

No, you want this neural network to work across all users.

I think the right thing to do is to partition your data set into training and test sets across all users.  Put the test set aside and train your neural network.

Once you think you have a good model, run the test set against it and see what success rate you get.

Be careful about overfitting.  If your training set predicts too well, you might be guilty of overfitting.  It'll show up with a poor result on the test set.

You need to decide how high a success rate you need.  If your neural net is 80% predictive, is that good enough?  90%?  95%?  You should figure that out before you start.

You should read about bootstrapping.

Comment: thanks @duffymo I will do that. Is there a case where we may need per user classifier ?? The reason I am asking this question is it was written in one of the recommendation system book.

Comment: Per user classifier makes no sense to me if you wish to apply it across users.  You're looking for common characteristics, right?  Netflix uses data from all users like you, so they're determining that based on characteristics across users.  You should read "Programming Collective Intelligence".  It has a great chapter on recommendation systems.